# DynamoDBOperationConfig and QueryOperationConfig

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

what is the difference between amazon dynamodb QueryOperationConfig and DynamoDBOperationConfig? and when developer need to use them?

Answer (score 1):

A DynamoDBOperationConfig is part of the object persistence model API:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DotNetSDKHighLevel.html

A QueryOperationConfig is part of the document model API:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DotNetSDKMidLevel.html

They both can perform all of the DynamoDB API calls, they are just different APIs for interacting with the service. The object persistence model is great for saving/loading objects of the same type. The document model allows you to serialize native .NET JSON types to DynamoDB types seamlessly.